# What am I supposed to do with the pressure plate and statue for 'The Ultimate Heist' quest in Oblivion?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-iv-oblivion

I am doing The Ultimate Heist quest in Oblivion and I have gotten to the part where I step on the pressure plate and the statue turns. I don´t know what to do because every time I move out of the little box the statue turn back around. What do I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the wiki](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Oblivion:The_Ultimate_Heist#Hall_of_Epochs):

> When you stand on the pressure plate, the keyhole in the Keyhole Pillar is opened up; if you step off the plate, the keyhole closes again. Only your presence on the plate triggers the keyhole; other creatures or corpses will not be recognized. Therefore, you need to be standing on the plate when you fire the Arrow of Extrication. Careful aiming is necessary because you only have one Arrow of Extrication, and it is a long distance shot. ... Aim at the cross formed at the hilt of the statue's sword, or possibly slightly lower, where the top of the statue's hands come together.

Just save your game when you stand on the pressure plate and practise with some iron arrows. I played the game three times and still remember that shooting that arrow was pretty hard and that I missed a few times.
Make sure to clear out all the enemies and take your time to shoot the arrow.